# KB8000822 Pending Install after removal

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

unfortunately we fell victim to Microsoft's KB5000808, 802 and 822 updates.. the latter being on our print server which was falling over everytime someone printed to a Kyocera printer.

I've managed to uninstall the update with the WUSA /UNINSTALL /KB:5000822 command and I've set it for removal via our WSUS server but irritatingly it says it is pending installation when I check in the Update settings on the server.

Is there a way of stopping this from being available to install?
I've cleared the software distribution folder but nothing seems to get rid of it.

thanks in advance,

Paul.

Comment: Can you start a scan from the UI, or is the button unavailable ?

Comment: when you say a scan what do you mean (for updates?)

Comment: Can you click on "Check for Updates" in the Windows Update user interface ?